# Adding Outlook Attachments in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

My code was running fine until attachments came up.

What I am trying to do.

1. All email addresses are in Column B.
2. In column C there are file paths as well as file names next to each email address. (C:\desktop\test.xlsm)
3. I am trying to automate the process of sending out emails to these addresses with these attachments. A user form pops out that prompts any CC, subject, text for the mass emails.

Here is the code

```
Dim SendTo As String
Dim Atmt As String
Dim ToMSg As String

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        Atmt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value

        SendTo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2)
            If SendTo <> "" Then
                ToMSg = DraftBox.Value
                Send_Mail SendTo, ToMSg
            End If

    Next i

    Unload Me

End Sub


Sub Send_Mail(SendTo As String, ToMSg As String)
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookMail As Object

    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)


    With OutlookMail
        .To = SendTo
        .CC = CC.Value
        .BCC = BCC.Value
        .Subject = Subject.Value
        .Body = ToMSg
```

> ```
>         .attachments.add Atmt
> ```

```
        .Send
```

I have attached the relevant code. It keeps telling me that Atmt is empty. Please help..

Comment: You didn't include it as a parameter.

Comment: attachments? i have.. It tells me no data source was provided. But when I copy paste the filepath+filename its sends out the email with the attachment

Comment: Something seems missing here? `Sub Send_Mail(SendTo As String, ToMSg As String)` Edit: did you write this code??? Edit2: missing from the call as well obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Send_Mail` sub you need to include an argument to pass the attachment path:

```
Sub Send_Mail(SendTo As String, ToMSg As String, Atmt as String)
```

Then when you call the `Send_Mail` sub, pass the argument you want provide:

```
Send_Mail SendTo, ToMSg, Atmt
```

The fact that I used `Atmt` was completely arbitrary and based on your example. You can call the String any name you want in your sub.

You could also make it work by declaring `Atmt` as a `Global` or `Public` variable outside the scope of any specific `Sub`. It currently is declared inside the first sub and so when you try to use it in the `Send_Mail` sub, the variable is unknown to that sub, so it tells you that it's empty.

I would steer more for the first method, though.